# Unraid Nginx Reverse Proxy GitLab-CE Docker

Tags: docker, nginx, reverse-proxy

I'm using Unraid 6.8.3 and got a letsencrypt docker for reverse proxy.

I got nextcloud and collabora running trough nginx in letsencrypt. But I cant get GitLab-CE to work trough nginx.

Infos:

Docker name: "GitLab-CE"

Docker repo: "gitlab/gitlab-ce"

Docker network is in custom proxy net

Web Interface Port (HTTP): 9080

Web Interface Port (HTTPS): 9443

SSH Port: 9022

Goal:

use git.domain.xyz

192.168.178.52:9022 -> git.domain.xyz:22

192.168.178.52:9080 -> git.domain.xyz:80

192.168.178.52:9443 -> git.domain.xyz:443

My gitlab.subdomain.conf:

```
server {
    listen 80 ssl;
    listen [::]:80 ssl;

    server_name git.*;

    include /config/nginx/ssl.conf;

    client_max_body_size 0;


    location / {
        include /config/nginx/proxy.conf;
        resolver 127.0.0.11 valid=30s;
        set $upstream_app GitLab-CE;
        set $upstream_port 9080;
        set $upstream_proto http;
        proxy_pass $upstream_proto://$upstream_app:$upstream_port;

    }
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    listen [::]:443 ssl;

    server_name git.*;

    include /config/nginx/ssl.conf;

    client_max_body_size 0;


    location / {
        include /config/nginx/proxy.conf;
        resolver 127.0.0.11 valid=30s;
        set $upstream_app GitLab-CE;
        set $upstream_port 9443;
        set $upstream_proto https;
        proxy_pass $upstream_proto://$upstream_app:$upstream_port;

    }
}

server {
    listen 22 ssl;
    listen [::]:22 ssl;

    server_name git.*;

    include /config/nginx/ssl.conf;

    client_max_body_size 0;


    location / {
        include /config/nginx/proxy.conf;
        resolver 127.0.0.11 valid=30s;
        set $upstream_app GitLab-CE;
        set $upstream_port 9022;
        set $upstream_proto ssh;
        proxy_pass $upstream_proto://$upstream_app:$upstream_port;

    }
}
```

Error I get in the log:

```
nginx: [emerg] no "ssl_certificate" is defined for the "listen ... ssl" directive in /config/nginx/site-confs/default:4
```

Answer (score 0):

Your server block

```
server {
    listen 80 ssl;
    listen [::]:80 ssl;
```

is configured to use ssl but there is not certificate and key configured for this server block.

If you realy want to serve if via http wihout terminate TLS, remove the ssl option from your configuration.

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
```

Comment: it worked with only using port 443 mapped to 9080. But is there a way to use ssh?

Comment: Do you mean SSL? Sure but to use SSL you need provide at least the key and cert file. Have a look here: http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/configuring_https_servers.html